# Why is there a ה in "מוהל"?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, brit-milah

The Hebrew word for the act performed at a circumcision is "לימול". The root [appears to be](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#1) נ.מ.ל. Following the exceptional [rules for roots whose first letter is נ](http://he.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%97_%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%92%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%94/%D7%97%D7%A4%22%D7%A0), the causative participle and nominative should be "ממיל" (with the second מ דגושה). Why then is the universal word for one who performs the act of circumcision "מוהל" as if the root is י.ה.ל ([e.g.](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93_%28%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A9%29)), which can't possibly be the case?

Comment: Not as if the root were י־ה־ל: then it'd be _mohil_, not _mohel_, right? It's as if the root were מ־ה־ל (_kal_ present).

Comment: Note that the verb many times in _l'shon Chazal_ acts as מ־ו־ל _kal_, as in the infinitive _lamul_ (in the _b'racha_), the past _mal_ (in "_mal v'lo fara k'ilu lo mal_"). I assume that in fact it _is_ מ־ו־ל _kal_ in _l'shon Chazal_. That doesn't help answer your question, though, AFAICT.

Comment: As soandos points out, מ־ו־ל _kal_ is found in _Tanach_ also. That __still__ doesn't help answer your question, though, AFAICT.

Comment: @msh210 - The י.ה.ל hypothesis is not perfect and _kal_ is more simple an explanation than _hif'il_, which necessitates mysteriously dropping the מ, but (a) some imperfects in _hif'il_ have a _tzere_ rather than a _chirik_ (such as the jussive) and (b) in the source _parasha_ there are several instances of the _hif'il_ to describe what Avraham did. As you mention, it is quite problematic no matter which way you slice it and I probably should have just left Occam's Razor alone.

Comment: The past-tense form at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7637 seems to imply it's מ־ה־ל _kal_.

Comment: related/possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78007/759

Answer (score 10):

The root is מול, sometimes considered a biliteral root, מל. Compare קם.

There are cases in the Semitic languages where a full consonant appears in the middle of such roots to "fill them out" to the usual triliteral form. Compare Aramaic רהט "run" (Hebrew רץ).

Comment: I like where this is going. Are there examples in Biblical Hebrew? Is מ.ל then _the same_ root as נ.מ.ל?

Comment: נמל simply reflects the nif'al. This is not common in פ"ו roots like קם, since most of these are intransitive.

Comment: _Sam_ is transitive; is _nisam_ (?) attested?

Comment: ...likewise _ban_. _Nivon_?

Comment: How do you translate "himol yimol"?

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud Yerushalmi in Mesechta Yevamos דף מג,ב פרק ח הלכה א uses the word as follows כההיא דאמר רבי הילא בשם רבי יסא הלוקח עבדים ערלים מן הגוי על מנת **למוהלן**. I guess that is the source of the **ה**

Comment: Are you suggesting that this Gemara added in a Hey for some reason, and everyone else is just for some reason referencing the Gemara when they speak, even though it isn't proper grammar?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the wrong root: http://ericlevy.com/Revel/BDB/BDB/14/num108.html#t59 what  נ.מ.ל gives. For the root see: http://ericlevy.com/Revel/BDB/BDB/13/mem32.html#t18

Comment: No, נ־מ־ל is the correct root, per _Rashi_ and _ibn Ezra_ to _B'reshis_ 17:11.

Comment: Had you looked down the page, it makes mention of "Aramaic מְהַל" which is where I believe the "he" comes from. With regards to the shoresh of the word, I can just tell you what I found, and it makes sense.

Comment: @WAF @msh210 you are assuming that mohel is or Hebrew origin, and that it shares the same shoresh as לימול. That is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Granted. Please elaborate [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/where-and-when-is-the-earliest-attestation-of-the-word-mohel).

Comment: [This midrash](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/where-and-when-is-the-earliest-attestation-of-the-word-mohel/7637#7637) is a pretty Hebrew source. Is there reason to believe it is either not the earliest?