# Where and when is the earliest attestation of the word "mohel"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew, brit-milah, employment

Where is the earliest attestation of the word *mohel* for one who performs the act associated with a ritual circumcision?

When was it written?

What language is it?

[Inspired by [Why is there a ה in "מוהל"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7621/why-is-there-a-in/7623#7623) ]

Comment: Your last line needs fixing.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Man, that was faster than I could say, "let me go get that link."

Comment: Are you specifically looking for מוהל used as a noun referring to the person who performs the cut, or any use of the verb which incorporates the radical ה?

Comment: The nominal, with the ה.

Answer (score 3):

הלוקח עבדים ערלים מן הגוי על מנת **למוהלן**, עבד איש את **מוהלו** בעל כורחו;

**תלמוד ירושלמי מסכת יבמות--**

[הערל פרל. שמיני יבמות](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35921&pgnum=160)

Comment: Both of those are verbs not nouns.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem (because I don't see it in the Mishna) that the earliest usage is the [Tosefta Brachot 6:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20419&st=&pgnum=45) (7:12 in some editions):

> המוהל צריך ברכה לעצמו או' ברוך על המילה
>   The Mohel must make a blessing himself [even if he is not the father?]. He says, "Baruch [...] Al HaMilah."

Comment: Is there conventional agreement on when Tosefta was written? There seems to be a wide [range of opinions](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%90).

Answer (score 1):

From a search on [Wikisource](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99), the earliest source found is [Midrash Rabbah (Shir Hashirim:1:12:3)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%92). Excerpt:

> אמרו לו תן לנו מה נאכל אמר להם כך אמר לי הקדוש ברוך הוא סינטומוס "כל ערל לא יאכל בו" מיד כל אחד ואחד נתן חרבו על ירכו **ומהל** עצמו מי מלן ר' ברכיה אמר משה היה **מוהל** ואהרן פורע ויהושע משקה וי"א יהושע היה **מוהל** ואהרן פורע ומשה היה משקה

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Talmud Yerushalmi is an earlier source though.

Comment: I agree, though am not sure. Unless it means the word מוהל and not its other forms?